# Logo not showing on top of header img

Tags: css, html

I busy in the process of creating a website and currently seem to be having an issue with logo that keeps hiding its self away.

I'm not to sure what I'm doing wrong I have added my html and css here so that hopefully some one can tell me what I have done wrong please.

I am currently using the html5 boilerplate template as well but have commented out the code in the mean time this is the html part of the code:

```
    <!--header --> 
    <div id="header">
    <div id ="logo"> 
            <h1><a href="index.html"></a></h1>
      </div>
      <div id= "hmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>    
</div>
```

this is the the css code for the header and logo and menu:

```
body,#container
{   margin:0;
    border:0;
    height:100%;
    font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:url(../Images/bgImg.png) repeat-x ;  
}

body > #container 
{
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
}   

#header
{
    background:url(../Images/hdBgImg.png);
    width:100%;
    height:115px;
}

#header #logo
{

     background:url(../Images/logo.png) no-repeat;
     width:272px;
     heigh:142px;
     cursor:pointer;
}   


#hmenu 
{
    font-size:38px;
    font-family:Tangerine, sans-serif;
    font-weight::bold;
    text-align:right;
    text-shadow:3px 2px 3px #333;
    border-radius:8px;
    position::absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;


} 
#hmenu ul
{
    height:auto;
    padding:8px 10px;
    margin:0.1em;
}

#hmenu li
{
    display:inline;
    padding:20px;
}

#hmenu a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#hmenu a:hover
{
    color:#8AAB8E;
    back:#fff;
}
```

when I try to get the logo added then it moves my menu of the header and it some how creates a double logo too.

any help would be great thanks.

Comment: @Ravyn, well, actually you just miss a "t" character at #header #logo selector for **height** rule, i see it work at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQYy9/)

Comment: in `#header #logo` style add `display: block` and heigh should be height as suggested above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

previous CSS code:

```
#header #logo
{
  background:url(../Images/logo.png) no-repeat;
  width:272px;
  heigh:142px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

suggested to fix

```
#header #logo
{
  background:url(../Images/logo.png) no-repeat;
  width:272px;
  height:142px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

let me share an updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RQYy9/1/) link

may you could see what's missing

Answer (score 0):

Change `heigh` to `height`:-

```
#header #logo
{
 background:url(../Images/logo.png) no-repeat;
 width:272px;
 height:142px;
 cursor:pointer;
 display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#header #logo
{
     background:url(Images/1.png) no-repeat;
     width:272px;
     height:142px;
     cursor:pointer;
display: inline-block;

}
```